# Cannot "find" Repeater inside a nested Accordian

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Accordion nested inside an Accordion.  I wasn't sure you could even do that, but you can!  It works. However...

In the inner Accordion, I have a repeater. When I try to set the RepeaterName.DataSource, I am getting a null reference exception.  I tried to force the issue by using this.FindControl, but still no joy.  The code behind just isn't seeing the Repeater inside the nested Accordion.

I'm frustrated, but not surprised.

I really don't want to "un-nest" these.  What I have is an Accordion of Authors, and then inside each Author Pane I have another Accordion of their works.

So, we have

Author1

- Article 1
- Article 2

Author2

- Article 1
- Article 2
- Article 3

etc.

EDIT: Adding markup and code behind

```
                        <AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="JohnBunyanPane">
                        <Header>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;John Bunyan</Header>
                        <Content>                            
                        <AjaxToolkit:Accordion ID="JohnBunyanInternalAccordion" runat="server"
                            SelectedIndex="-1"
                            CssClass="accordion"
                            HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
                            ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
                            AutoSize="None"
                            FadeTransitions="true"
                            TransitionDuration="250"
                            FramesPerSecond="40"
                            RequireOpenedPane="false"
                            SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
                            <Panes>
                                <AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="GraceAboundingPane">
                                    <Header>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Grace Abounding</Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:450px"> 
                                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="GraceAboundingUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:Repeater ID="GraceAboundingRepeater" runat="server">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <span>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="GraceAboundingBody" runat="server" Width="100%"  Text='<%# Eval("Body")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/separator.jpg" />
                                                        <br /><br />
                                                    </ItemTemplate> 
                                                </asp:Repeater>
                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </div>
                                    </Content>
                                </AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
                            </Panes>
                        </AjaxToolkit:Accordion>
                        </Content>
                    </AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

Here is the call to populate it:

```
            try
        {
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];

            var childAccordionPane = (AccordionPane)this.FindControl("JohnBunyanPane");
            var repeater = (Repeater)childAccordionPane.FindControl("GraceAboundingRepeater");
            //Repeater myRepeater = (Repeater)childAccordionPane.FindControl("GraceAboundingRepeater");
            //GraceAboundingRepeater.DataSource = myDataTable;
            //GraceAboundingRepeater.DataBind();

            repeater.DataSource = myDataTable;
            repeater.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: Can you access inner accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Your `FindControl` probably can't see into the AccordionPane.  You'll need to traverse down through the top-level (parent) AccordionPane.

Something like this:

```
var childAccordionPane = (AccordionPane)parentAccordionPane.FindControl("childAccordionPaneId");

var repeater = (Repeater)childAccordionPane.FindControl("repeaterId");
```

We can make it compile and work if given your markup to verify the strings representing each of the control IDs is correct.

Comment: Garrison,  sorry for the delay.  I've been unavailable for a few days here.  Conceptually I see what you're saying.  When I try to implement it, "(AccordianPane)" is not being recognized in the code behind.  Says it's not a recognized namespace.  Do I need a using statement to grab the library?

Comment: Okay... I got the reference, so it builds.  Still getting a null reference exception, but I'm liking this solution, and will continue to work with it till I get it to go.

Comment: If you give me your ASPX markup, I should be able to help you find it exactly.